# How should I distinguish intentional from parasitic series resistors in a schematic?

Tags: schematics, circuit-design

I need to show a few parasitic series resistors in my schematic. Is there a good way to distinguish these from intentional resistors, so it is easy to tell which is which?

---

Parasitic capacitors are a bit easier to do this since they are parallel parasitics and can have their leads shown in dotted lines, e.g. here as shown [from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tuned_RF_amplifier_stage.png):

[image]

Comment: dashed line works for me

Comment: I would draw them as resistors and indicate their nature in the reference designator, with an explanatory note, "RP1 to RPnnn are parasitic resistances, not physical components."

Comment: and/or draw a dashed rectangle around them?

Comment: @Brian's method is the one most often used, in my experience. Give them names like Rline (or Lwire for series inductance) and note what they are.

Comment: If you normally use American resistors (zig-zag line), use European resistors (box) for the parasitic ones.

Comment: I'm used to dashed lines. But this goes back to when you had real drafters doing the schematics from hand-drawn sources, instead of using software which may not support fully dashed wires and part images.

Comment: I can do dashed lines (I use [circuitikz](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz) which can draw pretty much everything as long as you don't mind steam coming out of your ears), they just look unnatural for series parasitics.

Comment: Different color or a lighter shade of gray could work too.

Comment: If you expect someone in the future to read this schematic, put it in words on the schematic. There are plenty of "what does this schematic symbol mean" questions posted here; anything outside the normal basic sch symbols will be hard to decode. Do yourself a favor and explain in a note on the schematic. Example: "Note 1: Rline models resistive drop across input wiring harness". Best if the words can be close to the reference, but if not, put a ( 1. ) at the site and Note 1 off in the corner of the same sheet.

Comment: if you mean the transformer indicate turns & Ohms 9T:20T DCR=__

Answer (score 1):

I normally draw a dashed line around the component and label differently to other components.

[image]